# Слово "достаточно"

Tags: выбор-слов, наречия

Здравствуйте.

Является ли грамотной фраза:
Ты считаешь меня достаточно тупым, чтобы самому решить, что делать?

Можно ли употреблять "достаточно" с отрицательными величинами (достаточно уродлив, достаточно медлителен)? Как правильно: "достаточно уродлив, чтобы занять первое" место или "достаточно уродлив, чтобы не занять первое место".

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше сказать:

Ты считаешь меня настолько тупым, чтобы самому решить, что делать? Это  нейтральный стиль.

Наречие "достаточно" не применяется по отношению к отрицательным характеристикам, обычно говорят о достаточности положительного качества. Однако в разговорной речи это выражение может использоваться для выражения иронии.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1)Ты считаешь меня настОлько тупым, чтобы самому решить, что делать?

Чтобы предложение было грамматически правильным, УДАРЕНИЕ должно падать на местоименное наречие. Тогда между двумя предложениями НЕТ ПРЯМОГО ОТНОШЕНИЯ "степень прилагательного + цель", а содержание примерное такое: ты постоянно указываешь мне на мои промахи, выставляя меня  весьма недалеким и тупым. А делаешь ты это для того, чтобы распоряжаться делами самому.

2) В нашей речи встречаются сложные варианты, где, с одной стороны, кажется нарушенной классическая грамматика, а с другой - больше экспрессии и выразительности. Это нестандартные конструкции, которые имеют право на существование, хотя и требуют  к себе особого внимания и понимания.

Answer (score 1):

> > Является ли грамотной фраза: Ты считаешь меня достаточно тупым, чтобы самому решить, что делать?

Не является грамотной. Прежде всего: кто этот "сам"? Адресат или автор фразы? Похоже, что адресат... Но двусмысленность налицо, так не говорят.

Сравните: " Ты считаешь меня достаточно умным, чтобы самому решать?.." Здесь "сам" – уже автор.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза неграмотная, даже предложенный разговорный стиль не допустит её в таком виде.

Наречие ДОСТАТОЧНО употребляется с прилагательными, выражающими положительный признак. Варианты правки:

***Ты считаешь меня настолько тупым, что я сам не могу решить, что делать?***

Работает пара НАСТОЛЬКО, ЧТО. Кроме того,  прибавилось необходимое для понимания смысла предложения ***подлежащее в первом придаточном предложении***.

(Ср.: **Ты считаешь меня достаточно умным, чтобы я сам мог решить, что делать?** Работает пара ДОСТАТОЧНО + прил., ЧТОБЫ.)